# Will ShareKit v0.2.1 stop working with Facebook soon?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is ShareKit going to stop working for Facebook sharing come 11th October 2011?
As I understand it the current version (0.2.1gm1) of ShareKit uses the REST api, which is based on the old iPhone SDK (facebook-iphone-sdk) and according to today's blog:

*On October 11th, apps using the old JavaScript Library (FeatureLoader.js) or the old iPhone SDK (facebook-iphone-sdk) for authentication will no longer be able to authenticate users until these apps switch to OAuth 2.0*

Or does it already use OAuth 2.0, so no changes are needed?
Just a little confused as to whether I need to update my apps in advance or not - thanks!

Comment: Well, from what I can tell, I think it does use Oauth 2.0 - I guess I'll find out for sure on 12th Oct!!!